# SEVERE: Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(Z)V

Tags: hibernate

I am using netbeans,
and want to integrate struts and hibernate for a simple application to display all the data of a table on a jsp page.

But i am getting the following error

```
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

At the logs of glassfish server i get following error

```
    SEVERE: Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
SEVERE: Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(Z)V
```

HibernateUtil.java:

```
package controller;

import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

/**
 * Hibernate Utility class with a convenient method to get Session Factory
 * object.
 *
 * @author ROMO
 */
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
            // config file.
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

FindQuestion.java:

```
package controller;

import beans.Question;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;

/*
 * @author ROMO
 */
public class FindQuestion extends ActionSupport {

    private String q = null;
    private String categoryname = null;
    private List questionList = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        q = "Question";
        categoryname = "Category";
        try {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            this.questionList = (List<Question>) session.createQuery("from Question").list();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

Can someone please Help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have *asm* version that is incompatible with your Hibernate version. One way to check for compatible versions is to take a look to the maven dependencies, here for example for  [hibernate-core](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core). It is usable way even if you do not maven builds.

One working combination for example is:

- Hibernate 3.6.10,
- cglib 2.2
- asm 3.1.

If you need answer that is more suited for you, you have to share information about which libraries are included at the moment.

Comment: i am actually very new to hibernate and maven. Can u please elaborate what exactly i need to do. On the link i am getting a list of hibernate binary versions but no idea what to do with it.

Comment: Hard to say exactly what is wrong without your full pom.xml file. Runtime your code expects to able to constructor in org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter. That seems to be impossible because version of asm you have does not have such a constructor. Incompatible version version can come indirectly via some other dependency in pom.xml.

Comment: I am not finding my pom.xml file as i am using netbeans not eclipse. And i dont know which asm is needed to be loaded. I also dont know anything how to deal with maven dependencies. I am frustrated for last 3 days. Please help.

Comment: How you manage your dependencies does not really matter. Point with maven repository was to show one place where you can find compatible versions. Answer contains now set working set Hibernate+asm+cglib.

Comment: As u said to resolve dependencies i need to update library. But when i replaced asm.jar with asm 1.5.3.jar i get the following error


C:\Documents and Settings\ROMO\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\ATest\nbproject\build-impl.xml:709: Warning: Could not find file C:\Documents and Settings\ROMO\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\ATest\lib\hibernate-persistence\asm.jar to copy.


Please help what to do. And guide what is proper way to update the hibernate libraries. I am using netbeans 7.1.2.

Comment: Maybe you can find out by yourself from the NetBeans documentation how to add new library to project and how to remove old.

Comment: I some how managed to add the new library. But i am not getting my output.

At glassfish server logs, i get the following error:


SEVERE: Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found


Now what may be the problem..?

Comment: Likely you do not have hibernate.cfg.xml at all or it is located to wrong directory. But that is kind of new topic. Maybe you can try to find help from Hibernate documentation and from existing Stack Overflow answers. If that does help, present new question with detailed information. If your original problem is now solved, you can accept this answer as told here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/171185

Comment: Thanks for pointing out.
last Error is removed.. But the final result is same. I am not getting  any output. However Now the new error at glassfish logs  :
"WARNING: Could not find action or result
There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name . - [unknown location]"


But i have already added the action in struts.xml as :
"<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="index"
                class="controller.FindQuestion">
            <result name="success">index.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>"

Now what can b the problem..?

Answer (score 1):

I found this:

http://www.hildeberto.com/2008/05/hibernate-and-jersey-conflict-on.html

Essentially, just in case the full explanation above goes:
I Fixed classloading issues with asm by using the cglib-nodep-2.2.3.jar. The reason why this needs replacing is that ASM is a popular library. Hibernate is built against asm 1.5.3 but asm is now at version 4. Somewhere, the class loaders in my container are picking up a much more recent version of asm and the class ClassWriter has been changed. Hibernate uses cglib under the covers, which in turn uses asm 1.5.3. This is the issue.  cglib-nodep was built to fix this issue. The asm classes have been moved from their standard package to a cglib package and it is these cglib versions that are used by the nodep library.

Spring adopts a very similar approach.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add to your pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-asm</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```