# compatibility issues with asm and hibernate and cglib...?

Tags: hibernate, cglib

I am getting the glassfish server logs:,

```
SEVERE: Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(Z)V
```

I am using netbeans.
I am frustrated for last 3 days.

Please help how to remove this error..?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SEVERE: Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(Z)V](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360825/severe-initial-sessionfactory-creation-failed-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this means is that your asm and cglib versions are out of sync. Try downgrading your asm library version and see if that helps.